# how to find tangent line at a given point, without equation

Tags: derivatives

Find the equation of the line that is tangent to the curve at the point $(0,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}})$. Given your answer in slope-intercept form.

I don't know how can I get the tangent line, without a given equation!!, this is part of cal1 classes.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ or $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$?  You could just respond with "the first one" or "the second one" and I will edit your question.

Comment: Do you have _anything_? Like a picture, or a verbal description of the curve?

Comment: the second one , thank you :)

Comment: no, that's the problem the question kind of missing something,

Comment: What is the dimension of the space where the curve lays?

Comment: There are infinite functions $\;f\;$ for which $\;f(0)=\sqrt\frac\pi2\;$ , and thus the question, as it is now, makes no sense.

Comment: We don't need an equation. A drawing of the shape of the curve or a verbal description of its shape or properties might give more clues.

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose that your curve is the graph of a function $y=f(x)$ such that $f(0) = \sqrt{\pi/2}$,  than the equation of the tangent at $x=0$ is:

$
y-\sqrt{\pi/2}=f'(0)(x-0)
$

i.e.

$y=f'(0) x+\sqrt{\pi/2}$

Answer (score 0):

So far we can infer
$$
T(x) = m x + n
$$
with $T(0) = \sqrt{\pi/2}$. Thus
$$
T(x) = m x + \sqrt{\pi/2}
$$
To determine the slope $m$ we need more information about the given curve.

Comment: thank you so much, for your help. and i'll try t see my teacher if there is a farther info about it. THX